# Azure Stream Analytics Job generates no output when using static reference data

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

I have written a query that uses a stream input and join it with static json reference data. I get the correct results when testing the query in "Test results" tab (uploading the same sample reference data). However, no output is generated when starting the job.

My query:

[image]

The stream input produces random results every second like :

[image]

And the json reference file is:

[image]

From the monitoring dashboard there are also no input events nor output.

I have confirmed that the output blob is created when no join with reference data is used in the query. I have uploaded the json reference data in a storage container and have provided the path pattern : ref/Atm.json in my example.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just curious and tried to repro , I am using a very similar query as yours .

```
SELECT sum(A.amount),B.area_code
INTO Gen2
FROMEHInput A
JOIN JSONref B ON A.ATMCode=B.atm_code
group by B.area_code,TumblingWindow(minute,1)
```

This is the output which you have.( all junk data , but it confirms query works )

{"sum":63580.0,"area_code":20}

{"sum":73060.0,"area_code":30}

{"sum":68220.0,"area_code":20}

At this point , I thought to making some changes to check if I can repro your case of no output , I just updated the static file to something non existing file , ASA never complained about that but I never got the results either  .
I think you  may be hitting the same ( as you mentioned that without the join things just works fine ) .
In my case I have the static file location something like

https://blobaccount.blob.core.windows.net/container/**File2/Atm.json**

and when i create the Reference Input , I pass the file name as

[image]

I think for some reason its getting messed up here .

Other thing which you can try it increase the TW to a bigger window .

Let me know how it goes .

Answer (score 1):

I managed to resolve this issue. The error as you suggested was the path pattern I had specified for my reference data. So I had created a container e.g. "mycontainer" and I just dropped the json files in it. The path pattern that worked for me was just the names of the json files inside that container. No "/" , just Atm.json in my example.

Now the stream job creates output files in my blob storage.